# Find the maximum of $\left|z_1-z_2\right|+\left|z_2-z_3\right|+\left|z_3-z_1\right|$

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima-minima

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3$ be complex numbers satisfying the condition $\left|z\right|^2\leq 4\left|z+\overline{z}\right|+33$. Find the maximum value of
$$P=\left|z_1-z_2\right|+\left|z_2-z_3\right|+\left|z_3-z_1\right|$$

---

If $z=a+bi$ then $a^2+b^2\leq 8\left|a\right|+33 \Leftrightarrow \left(\left|a\right|-4\right)^2+b^2\leq 49$. This follows that $z_i$ belongs to the union of two circles $\left(x-4\right)^2+y^2\leq 49$ (when $Re z_i>0$) and $\left(x+4\right)^2+y^2\leq 49$ (when $Re z_i<0$). Let $A,B,C$ be the points responding to $z_1,z_2,z_3$. Then $P=AB+BC+CA$. I have no idea to find the maximum value of $P$. But when I choose $z_1=-8+\sqrt{33}i, z_2=-8-\sqrt{33}i, z_3=11$, I can see $P=2\sqrt{33}+2\sqrt{394}$. I cannot find any other triple $\left(z_1,z_2,z_3\right)$ so that $P$ is greater. Help me some ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Why $P=AB+BC+CA$?

Comment: @user Presumably the notation $AB$ is the geometric notation for distance between $A$ and $B$, which is precisely $|z_1-z_2|$.

Comment: @user because $|z_1-z_2|$=dist(A,B)="AB".

Comment: @JeanMarie I see. I thought $AB $ stays for product of $A $ and $B $.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, I mean $z_2=-8-\sqrt{33}i$. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use  $$ z_1=q+\bigg[\sqrt{49-(q+4)^2}\bigg]i, \\z_2=q-\bigg[\sqrt{49-(q+4)^2}\bigg]i,\\ z_3=11 $$
you should find $q_{max} = -8$

Comment: My guess is this is what they did to find their candidate for the maximum. It makes intuitive sense that this should be the maximum, but as I understand it, they're asking for a proof that the maximum perimeter occurs on this 1-dimensional parametrization of triangles.